# What is the meaning of this OpenCV Matrix Expression?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I need help to understand this code snippet about alpha channel blending better. There are 2 Mat data type and both of them are split to get the alpha channel (`[3]` is the alpha channel of RGBA). Then there is 1 more Mat variable called `multiplier` which I don't really understand the purpose and how the operation on this variable works.

```
split(mat1, mat1_split);
split(mat2, mat2_split);
Mat multiplier = (mat1_split[3] & mat2_split[3])/255 + 1;  //Need explanation here
```

If I extend the definition of `&` between `mat1_split[3]` and `mat2_split[3]` on Visual Studio, it will show this definition `CV_EXPORTS MatExpr operator & (const Mat& a, const Mat& b);` .

This probably looks like a beginner question but I couldn't understand the meaning of `multiplier` operation above.

Comment: @user1241241 what bug?

Comment: fixed by @HansHire\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look at the following example:

```cpp
cv::Mat mat1 = cv::Mat(150, 150, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255));
cv::rectangle(mat1, cv::Point(0, 0), cv::Point(49, 150), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0, 64), cv::FILLED);
cv::rectangle(mat1, cv::Point(50, 0), cv::Point(99, 150), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0, 128), cv::FILLED);

cv::Mat mat2 = cv::Mat(150, 150, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255, 255));
cv::rectangle(mat2, cv::Point(0, 0), cv::Point(150, 49), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255, 64), cv::FILLED);
cv::rectangle(mat2, cv::Point(0, 50), cv::Point(150, 99), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255, 128), cv::FILLED);

std::vector<cv::Mat> mat1_split;
std::vector<cv::Mat> mat2_split;

cv::split(mat1, mat1_split);
cv::split(mat2, mat2_split);
cv::Mat inter = mat1_split[3] & mat2_split[3];
cv::Mat multiplier = (mat1_split[3] & mat2_split[3]) / 255 + 1;

cv::imwrite("images/mat1.png", mat1);
cv::imwrite("images/mat2.png", mat2);
cv::imwrite("images/inter.png", inter);
cv::imwrite("images/multiplier.png", multiplier);
```

We have `mat1` like this:

[image: mat1]

And, we have `mat2` like this:

[image: mat2]

Partly transparencies for `mat1` and `mat2` are `64` and `128`, see above code.

The intermediate result (`inter`) of the binary AND operator `&` looks like this:

[image: inter]

Since this is binary AND, you'll get `0` for the combination of `64` and `128` (first row, second column as well as second row, first column), but - for example - you'll get `64` for the combination of `64` and `64` (first row, first column). On the other hand, you'll also get `64` for the combination of `64` and `255` (first row, third column as well as third row, first column).

So, that's the "syntactic" part, but the "semantic" behind that? I guess, you'll need to ask the author of this code snippet. I don't get the point of cancelling out alpha channels, if they don't match (`64` and `128`), but keeping them if they do (`64` and `64`). (Especially, if you keep in mind, that combining `64` and `127` would also give `64`...)

The `multiplier` is `1` for all pixels, where the combined value is less or equal `127`, and `2` otherwise. Again, for the "semantic" part, ask the author.

Hope that helps - at least a bit.

Comment: Great and detail answer! I have a question how do you get 0 for 64 and 128, and 64 for 64 and 64? Is there any mathematical tutorial for AND operation on binary that I can follow? Also, the purpose of this program is to stitch frames from video to create 1 image, is that making any sense to your question about "the point of cancelling out alpha channels, if they don't match but keeping them if they do" ?

Comment: @gameon67 You could start at the [Wikipedia article on bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). `64` is `0010 0000`, and `128` is `0100 0000`. Using binary AND on each bit then gives `0000 0000`, which is `0`. On the other issue, therefore one might need to see the rest of the code, but I guess, this exceeds the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking bit/pixel intensity wise operation

& -> And operation it take the highest value of all inputs  input 0 0 > 0   0 1>1 1 0 >1   1 1 > 1

there are many others such as

| -> or operation

for others operant such as XOR, NOT, NAND, NOR and XNOR, im not sure opencv allows or not, you are free to try